# Right pane in Console tab in Firebug greyed out

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, firefox-addon, firebug

In the HTML tab in Firebug (1.12.14) I can get the js-code pane to show up at the bottom.

The right pane in Console tab is greyed out though, i.e. I cannot write any code into it. Why is this, and how can I enable it?

Comment: What happens if you twiddle `extensions.firebug.enableOrion` in about:config? I think I recall seeing a few extension conflicts take this form. Do you use any Firebug extensions?

Comment: Changing the configs didn't do much, but I disabled almost all addons and restarted FF and now the multi-line console panse works! :)